# ImageView inside Gridview repeating image when scrolling (using ImageDownloader)

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, repeat

As the title says, I have this problem.

Because I need to retrieve images from the network, I have implemented a solution which is explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

I will post the Adapter and ImageDownloader code (I have taken the liberty to modify the downloader in order to make the functionality more appropriate to my program).

Adapter method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_adapter_camera_layout, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_image);
        holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_name);
        holder.text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        holder.text.setLines(2);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    imgDownloader.download(values.get(position).getUrl(), holder.image, holder.progress);
}
```

And here is the ImageDownloader (I post just the most proper part of the code, if you need further don't hesitate to ask for it).

```
public void download(String url, ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progress) {

    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(url);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else if(cancelPotentialDownload(url, imageView)){
        BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView, progress);
        imageView.setTag(new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(task));
        task.execute(url);
    }
}

private boolean cancelPotentialDownload(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imageView);

    if (bitmapDownloaderTask != null) {
        String bitmapUrl = bitmapDownloaderTask.url;
        if ((bitmapUrl == null) || (!bitmapUrl.equals(url))) {
            bitmapDownloaderTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            // The same URL is already being downloaded.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    if (imageView != null && imageView.getTag() != null) {
        return ((WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>) imageView.getTag()).get();
    }
    return null;
}

public class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    String url;
    WeakReference<ImageView> viewReference;
    WeakReference<ProgressBar> progressReference;

    public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView view, ProgressBar progress) {
        view.setTag(false);
        viewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(view);
        progressReference = new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        url=params[0];
        Log.e("DOWNLOAD URL", url);
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (isCancelled())
            result = null;

        addBitmapToCache(url, result);

        if (viewReference != null) {
            ImageView imgView = viewReference.get();
            BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask = getBitmapDownloaderTask(imgView);

            if (this == bitmapDownloaderTask) {
                if (result != null)
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
                else
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_signal);
            }
        }

        if (progressReference != null) {
            ProgressBar prog = progressReference.get();
            if (prog != null)
                prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest for u to use a library for the image downloading, [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) does a great job for it. Another thing take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs&list=PLE9zhYKdr-MGGQszkwsYbfCDPBofO6NtV&index=3) video from dev-bytes. Its about animations but the trick should be the same for downloading images. Those two steps should work, I've done that a few times and it worked perfcetly.

Comment: This library is awesome! I will remember this when I need to use dynamic imageviews